# Covert from String to SHA256

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am a beginner of delphi.
In Delphi XE2, I can use my function to convert from **String** to **Sha256**. But my function is not work in Delphi7. Are there any functions in Delphi7 for converting from **String** to **Sha256**? This is my function:

```
function GetSHA256Str(const str : Ansistring) : Ansistring;
begin
  IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
  with TIdHashSHA256.Create do
  try
    Result := LowerCase( HashStringAsHex(str) );
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  IdSSLOpenSSL.UnLoadOpenSSLLibrary;
end;
```

Comment: The code works just as well in D7 but you've been caught out by text encoding. Do you know what encoding is used in the two variants? That is Unicode Delphi and non Unicode Delphi? Furthermore why are you using AnsiString in Unicode Delphi? What you really should be doing is using string and converting to UTF8 bytes. And being explicit about encoding. As I gave said so many times don't leave encoding to chance. Don't hash or encrypt text. Operate on bytes, binary data.

Comment: Because of I am a beginner of delphi, so i can't understand well about what you said. I just found this code on internet. I can't make this function myself.  May you help me to make a function to convert from __GoOnToProcess__ to __7bc361b609c67b3005bef521781862e71d2ceb1acf8c8713cd141f7135cf0325__

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* This site does not exist to do your work for you. This community aims to build a resource of Q&A topics. If you need help with your work please ask your supervisor.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and wrote these: http://yoy.be/md5.html (It says MD5, but there's SHA256 in there as well)

Comment: You're not new here. You should know that answers containing nothing but a link to off-site resources are not acceptable here.

Comment: @StijnSanders, Thank you so much for your answer, it really helpful to me.